# JUnit: how to access Spring configuration as Spring has intended?

Tags: spring, junit

There is a [tutorial video](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Mastering-Spring-MVC-3) that introduces Spring MVC 3.0. In the demo-project they use the following directory structure:

```
<proj>
   src
      main
         webapp
            WEB-INF
               spring
                  appServlet
                     controllers.xml
                     servlet-context.xml
                  root-context.xml
```

Let's say I have a project with Maven-support and I want to write JUnit tests using Spring's configuration. Currently we use JUnit 4.8.2. This would obviously require to load the three files listed above.

In the test I could use annotations like

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("classpath*:/WEB-INF/spring/**/*.xml")
```

However, that doesn't find the XML-files. I took a look at the classpath and noticed, that only the `<proj>/target/classes` and `<proj>/target/test-classes` are included by default.

One obvious solution would be to add the proper path to the classpath, but I don't know if that is what the guys at Spring had in mind.

Therefore, my question: What do I need to do to load the configuration files while letting it look as if I'm the total pro-coder using Spring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put the "normal" spring configuration in the resources folder but not in the webapp folder: `src\main\ressources\WEB-INF\spring\root/spring-context.xml`.  Then you can access it without problems from the test.

Put only the web related spring configuration (servlet-context.xml) in the `webapp` folder.

---

The structure that you described is the one generated by the STS-Spring-Template:MVC-Template, however Spring-ROO and Spring-Fuse generate the structure that I have described.
For example Spring ROO:

```
<project>/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml
<project>/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/webmvc-config.xml
<project>/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml
```

web.xml:

```xml
...
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath*:META-INF/spring/applicationContext*.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: This contradicts with what the lecturer uses in the video. I'm aware of your solution and I agree that this would work. But if your suggestion is the best approach I'm wondering what to put into the various XML-files. Or: why did they use the directory structure I listed in the first place?

Comment: @sjngm: I have examined so many example and templates from Spring-Source, and every has an bit other structure, so I guess they do not have a common best practice approach. -- btw see my extended answer

Comment: ouch, I thought they had only one fine solution for this ;). Thanks for your edit.

Answer (score 5):

Another option is to use file system resource loader:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml")
```

Comment: Kind of works, but if your context itself has "classpath:" references none of them will work.